# Too much time on onmeasure method after setImageBitmap of ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

long time reader, first time asker so please be gently ;)

I have an Android code that displays around  10 pictures in second on ImageView.
(calling setImageBitmap on ImageView to set new bitmap)
This causes display lags so I'm trying to speed it as much as I can.

I found that (with traceview) that app spend a lot of time on methods:

```
ViewRoot.performTraversals
View.measure
FrameLayout.onmeasure
ViewGrou.measureChildWithMargins
```

I suspecting on ImageView measuring so i have create CustomImageView and overide onMeasure just to call super method and write sysout.

It seems that after every setImageBitmap onmeasure is called 3 times.
Bitmaps are allways of the same size so there is no change. Actually it can be change from time to time  when image source is changed but that should be remeasured only then.

What can I change, overide, do to eliminite this measurement impact on application speed?

If you need further information tell me and I will provide it.

Sample code

```
final Bitmap bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, width, height, false);
imageView2.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
if (setSize) {
    setSize(imageView2, width, height);
}
imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmapScaled);
```

Method that I change to make it work faster (possibly not safe?!)

```
boolean layout=true;

int noL=1;

@Override
public void requestLayout() {
    if (layout){
        super.requestLayout();              
        if (noL>10){
            layout=false;
        }else{
            noL++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a snippet of your code that enable us to replicate and help you out with the problem? This doesn't seem to be an obvious problem that anyone can jump in without code context.

Comment: Snippent wont change match because problem lies in only one line setImageBitmap when this is done often. I kind of solve it with custom image view and override of requestlayout method. I change this method so it will call super 10 times and no more and it works and save a lot of time. Still intersted in proper solution because I'm not sure if this will give me a headache somewhere else.

Comment: Just do setImageBitmap 10 times with random picture basically and see how to improve the lag? I am just surprised by the lag as 10 pictures is nothing. That's why I am asking for code snippet to see if there is any other problem causing this one. As a long time reader, you should know how the code snippet help anyone to answer a particular question and understand the context better

Comment: And ofcourse thanks for your participation :)

Answer (score 6):

When I had a similar problem I did the following:

```
public class ImageViewEx extends ImageView{
    private boolean makeRequest;
    public ImageViewEx(Context context){
        super(context);makeRequest=true;
    }
    public ImageViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }
    public ImageViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyle);
         makeRequest=true;
    }
    public void setImageBitmapNoRequestLayout(Bitmap bitmap) {
        makeRequest = false;
        setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        makeRequest = true;
    }
    @Override public void requestLayout(){
        if(makeRequest)super.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Now changing the bitmap with `setImageBitmapNoRequestLayout(...)` does not call `requestLayout()`.